# Shift + Enter is a vertical tab but not a new paragraph

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am trying to get the paragraphs of a Word doc with the Office JS API.

```
const body = context.document.body;
context.load(body, 'paragraphs/items/text');
await context.sync();
const pars = body.paragraphs.items;
```

But when I press Shift + Enter it is a vertical tab in the text of the containing paragraph (https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer/?q=%0B) and not a new paragraph in Word.

Is there a way to get these paragraphs without searching for vertical tabs in each paragraph and then search the text in front of it and the text behind it to get the ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Word uses Carriage Return to define the end of a paragraph. A Line Feed, or vertical tab, forces a new line but not a new paragraph. If you need to distinguish ranges separated by a Line Feed, you can use the [Pararaph.split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=office-js#split-delimiters--trimdelimiters--trimspacing-) method, and split with the Line Feed.

Comment: Currently I am doing paragraph.getTextRanges(<list with all special chars (e.g.: `[' ', '.', ',']`)>, true) to get all words of the paragraph. I tried to use `String.fromCharCode(11)` as one of the chars, but the result was sth like `['text', 'text<verticaltab>text', 'text']`

Comment: Try \v (vertical tab)